# Upgrading an old project from NHibernate 1.2 to 3.3

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

WE have an old project, which was originally written in .NET 2.0 and VS2005, which ended up in VS2008. It uses NHibernate 1.2 for data access. As part of our upgrade, we moved to .NET 4.0 and VS2010, but we are having some problems with the move from NHibernate 1.2 to 3.3.

The main problem we are having is querying a table, which has a link on it. The query we are running is as follows:

```
IQuery query = base.Session.CreateSQLQuery("select t from Transaction t inner join Order o where TransactionDate >= ? && TransactionDate <= ? order by TransactionDate desc");
```

We get 2 different errors: either t.Transaction or t.Orders does not exist in the database. We know these tables exist, i have checked multiple times, and i know there is data in there...

I have seen the Question [What to be aware of when upgrading from NHibernate 1.2 to 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388500/what-to-be-aware-of-when-upgrading-nhibernate-from-1-2-to-3-2) and it mentions that we may need to modify our mapping files... but does not mention what needs to be changed... Is there something that will look at our mapping files and tell us what needs to change? I will admit, this is my first time using NHibernate at the lower level (actually talking to the DB). up till this point, all database stuff was already "done"... its only now with the upgrade that the problems have occurred...

Answer (score 0):

Since `CreateSQLQuery`, as the name implies, executes raw SQL, the only explanation I can think of is that you are connecting to the wrong database.

Considering you're using `?` for the parameter place holders, I know you're not using SQL Server... so it's probably a DB that requires data source configuration outside of the connection string.

That opens the option of something I've seen before: 32bit and 64bit drivers using different configuration files/registry keys.

Comment: I've been watching **Elementary** today... :-)

Comment: Hmmm.... machine is 64 bit, IIS is told to run as 32bit due to an issue with a 3rd party control... That could be it... Thanks... Will try that in the morning!

Comment: Havent managed to get it working yet... Tried different machines, different versions of the MySQL drivers, etc... no luck... back to square one... :( I have, however, started watching Elementary! Thanks for that! :)